# FTP link to work in all browsers (Chrome, IE9, Firefox)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-9

Is there a winning combination that will make a FTP link work in all the browsers?

- Works in Chrome + Firefox but doesn't work in IE9: `ftp://username:password@ftpserver/folder`
- Works only in IE9, but not in the others: `ftp://username:password@ftpserver/path/to/folder`

Seems that IE9 only works if you give it an absolute path. Anybody found a better solution?

Comment: what? do chrome and ff support relative ftp paths??? i thought they all need the whole path. am i missing something here?

Comment: Note: Google Chrome 82 won't support FTP anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have another problem than browser incompatibility. I just tried all 3 browsers and they all acted the same way with the same FTP url. Maybe there is some kind of a shortcut/redirection path in your FTP root and other browsers support this but IE9 doesn't (I don't think so but trying to see what might be wrong). Otherwise, all 3 browsers should be able to see the same root and should work with same paths according to my tests with my FTP servers.

Comment: I think you're on to something. I just tried an external FTP and it worked. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `ftp://username:password@ftpserver/folder/` (add the trailing slash if it is a folder). This works in IE too.

By the way, I suppose there is no such notion as absolute path in FTP links: all FTP paths are treated as being originated from FTP root folder.

Comment: it also works without slash at the end with all browsers. just tested it.

Comment: In my case, IE suggests to save a file instead of browsing a folder when it opens the first-level folder for the first time, i.e. `ftp://server.com/folder` does not open propertly, but `ftp://server.com/folder/` does, and after that so does `ftp://server.com/folder`. Folders of deeper levels (e.g. `ftp://server.com/folder/subfolder`) open in my IE without any problems - without the slash as well.

Comment: I tried `ftp://server.com` `ftp://server.com/folder` `ftp://server.com/folder/subfolder` and they all worked for me. Win7+IE9

Comment: I've tried with/without trailing slash and it makes no difference. I didn't came with the idea of adding an absolute path by myself, but I can't find the link where I first say this idea.